# Opening a Specific Record in an Access Form From Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm writing a macro that will open an Access Database, open a form and display a specific record based on the contents of the ActiveCell. I have it mostly working, but the problem I'm having is that it opens a form that only contains the one record, so the arrow buttons at the bottom don't go to other records. Is there a way to open the form with all the records and then move to then one i want to show? I suspect it has to do with the search box at the bottom of the form, but I can't find any info about it on the internet.

Form opened by Macro:
[image]

Form opened manually:
[image]

```
Sub File_open()
Dim app as Object
Dim search As String: search = ActiveCell.Value

If (ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 3) And (InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "-") <> 0) Then
    'Open NCR Record
    Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    app.Visible = True
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase ("Z:\Quality\NCR Database\NCR Databse " & "20" & Left(ActiveCell.Value, 2) & "0101.accdb")
    app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID]=" & Abs(Replace(Right(search, 4), "-", ""))
    Set app = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If
Msbox ("NCR Not Found.")
End Sub
```

UPDATE:
I've noticed that users of this database have been sloppy and the `[ID]` of the records don't line up with the number I get from my `Abs(Replace(Right(search, 4), "-", ""))` expression. I want to look at a textbox named `[Title]` whose control source is a field called `[NCR Number]` and use the `search` variable as is to find the record. I changed my code and now I just get a input box that is completely baffling to me:

[image]

```
    app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", WhereCondition:="[Title]=" & search
```

Comment: You applied a filter, as indicated by the word `Filtered`next to arrows!. Click on it to remove the filter. You may want to use [Recordset.FindFirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao). This can be done on Form_load, with the searched value provided by OpenArgs.)

Comment: Use fieldnames in queries not controlsname. [NCR Number] is a string? Then use`[NCR Number] = '" & Replace(search,"'","''") & "'"` (Replace is to avoid error if [NCR Number] contains a quote(`'`)).

Comment: `[Title]`/`[NCR Number]` and `search` is always a number formatted like this: 19-0001. Using `[NCR Number]` for the where condition just opens the form to a new entry, and I've double checked that `search` is identical to the data in that field. I've tried using other text boxes on the form, and I get even more confusing outcomes. `WhereCondtion:="[Program]=" & "SE07"` brings up an input box asking me for the parameter value of SE07, not Program.

Comment: Formatted numbers have been converted to strings! So you need the quote before and after search! Same on SE07! The criteria is the datatype of the field, not its contents-

Comment: `WhereCondition:="[NCR Number]='" & search & "'"` works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing the form with [`DoCmd.OpenForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openform):

> *expression.OpenForm (FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)*

For `FormName` you're passing `"Issue Details"`, skipping `View` and `FilterName` parameters, and then you provide a `WhereCondition` argument:

```vb
app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", , , "[ID]=" & Abs(Replace(Right(search, 4), "-", ""))
```

That `"[ID]=" & Abs(Replace(Right(search, 4), "-", ""))` expression *is* the filter you're seeing.

Remove that argument, you'll remove the filter.

```vb
app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details"
```

Side note, don't skip optional positional arguments like that (`, , ,`) - consider using *named arguments* instead, it makes it much clearer what arguments go to what parameters:
Now you need to move the recordsets cursor to your wanted position (can be provided by`.OpenArgs`):

```vb
app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Issue Details", _
    OpenArgs:="[ID]=" & Abs(Replace(Right(search, 4), "-", ""))
'below could be in the form itself, e-g- Form_Load, (then ref by Me)
With Forms("Issue Details").RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst Forms("Issue Details").OpenArgs
    If .NoMatch then
       ' reaction on id not found
    Else
        Forms("Issue Details").Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Does that code have to be in `Form_Load` or is there a way to keep all the code in my excel macro? My code has changed a little, see my edited question above.

Comment: @BreadDoughlas that code invokes `OpenForm`, it's opening the form... it doesn't belong in a `Form_Load` handler, no.

Comment: @BreadDoughlas But it could be used there (all after OpenForm). Useful if this is needed at multiple locations.

Comment: Now that I have my argument figured out, this is working great. I just had to change `Forms("Issue Details")` to app.Forms('Issue Details)